# Issue with removing margins in Divi theme

Tags: css

[image]

I am working on a project in Divi. I have 2 issues that I am unable to resolve. The first issue is I am unable to remove the margin in divi. In the section there were 2 margins one on the left and one on the right but I can only get rid of one not both. The css I have used is as follows

```css
#tasktrackxx{
  background-image:url(https://www.greenpassage.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/2020-01-09_20-38-36.png); 
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height:650px;
}
```

```html
<html>  
    <head>  

        <script src="../wp-content/plugins/getaddress/dist/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../wp-content/plugins/getaddress/dist/js/timeline.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../wp-content/plugins/getaddress/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../wp-content/plugins/getaddress/dist/css/timeline.min.css" />
  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <div class="container" id="tasktrackxx">
   <div id="tasktrack">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            <div class="main-div">
                                <div class="pcode1">
                                    <table style="border:0px!important;border-top-width: 0px;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="border-bottom: 1px;border-top-width: 0px!important;width: 314px;">
                                                <input type="text" name="task_id" style="border:0px;height:45px; border-radius:20px!important; width: 250px;padding:10px!important"placeholder="Enter your Tracking ID" value="<?= isset($_POST['task_id']) ? $_POST['task_id'] : '' ?>" required="required"></td>
                                            <td style="border-top-width: 0px!important;"><button type="submit" name="task-track" style="border:0px!important;width:150px;" class="btn btn-default getCalculation btn-amount" alt="Submit">Submit</button></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                       </form>
                    </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                 <div class="timeline">
                        <div class="timeline__wrap">
                            <div class="timeline__items">
                            <?php
                            if(isset($data) && $data!='' && $data->state!='') { 
                                $Xstate=$data->state;
                                for ($row = 0; $row < $Xstate; $row++){
                                ?>
                                 <div class="timeline__item">
                                        <div class="timeline__content">
                                            <?php
                                            for ($col = 0; $col < 1; $col++) {
                                            ?>
                                            <h2><?php echo $state[$row][1]; ?></h2>
                                         <p><?php echo $state[$row][2]; ?></p>
                                            <?php }?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php
                            }}
                            ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
   </div>
   </div>  
  </div>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: @halfer - I got it thanks

Comment: This issue has now been resolved by css which the theme owner divi provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has now been resolved by css which the theme owner divi provided.